# I have tried to deploy my react.js application to heroku after my lastest commit to github. But i got an error. Can't sleep for days

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I committed and pushed my project to GitHub. When I try to push to Heroku by running this command:

```
git push heroku master
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app.js 8:0-52
remote:        Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './store/configurestore' in '/tmp/build_fc37f7a6/src'
remote:        resolve './store/configurestore' in '/tmp/build_fc37f7a6/src'
remote:          using description file: /tmp/build_fc37f7a6/package.json (relative path: ./src)
remote:            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:            using description file: /tmp/build_fc37f7a6/package.json (relative path: ./src/store/configurestore)
remote:              no extension
remote:                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                /tmp/build_fc37f7a6/src/store/configurestore doesn't exist
remote:              .js
remote:                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                /tmp/build_fc37f7a6/src/store/configurestore.js doesn't exist
remote:              .json
remote:                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                /tmp/build_fc37f7a6/src/store/configurestore.json doesn't exist
remote:              .wasm
remote:                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                /tmp/build_fc37f7a6/src/store/configurestore.wasm doesn't exist
remote:              as directory
remote:                /tmp/build_fc37f7a6/src/store/configurestore doesn't exist
remote:
remote:        webpack 5.70.0 compiled with 1 error in 13696 ms
remote: error Command failed with exit code 1.
remote:        info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
remote: error Command failed with exit code 1.
remote:        info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
 We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to new-react-expensify-app.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/new-react-expensify-app.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/new-react-expensify-app.git'
```

This is my `package.json` file:

```
  {
  "name": "expensify",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Emmanuel",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "live-server public/",
    "build:dev": "webpack",
    "build:prod": "webpack --mode production --env production",
    "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "test": "jest --config=jest.config.json",
    "start": "node server/server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "yarn run build:prod"
  },"engines": {
    "node": "17.4.0",
    "yarn":"1.22.17"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.17.12",
    "babel-cli": "6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.5.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "enzyme": "3.0.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.0.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.6.2",
    "express": "4.15.4",
    "live-server": "^1.2.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.6.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "node": "4.9.0",
    "node-sass": "7.0.1",
    "normalize-css": "^2.3.1",
    "raf": "3.3.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-addons-shallow-compare": "15.6.0",
    "react-dates": "^21.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-modal": "2.2.2",
    "react-redux": "5.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0",
    "redux": "3.7.2",
    "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "uuid": "3.1.0",
    "validator": "8.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.70.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.2",
    "babel-jest": "^28.1.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2"
  }
}
```

This is my `src/app.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import AppRouter from './routers/AppRouter';
import configureStore from './store/configurestore';
import 'normalize-css';
import './styles/styles.scss';
import "react-dates/initialize";
import 'react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css';

const store = configureStore();

const jsx = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AppRouter />
  </Provider>
);
ReactDOM.render(jsx, document.getElementById('app'));
```

This my file structure in src folder

[image: Image of my file structure in src foler]

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is just a typo. Make sure to spell the file name correctly: `import configureStore from './store/configureStore';` (capital `S`). Windows treats those filenames as the same thing by default, but Linux (which Heroku uses) does not.

Comment: Does the code works on your localhost?

Comment: Yeah @JRichardsz, Everything works fine on my localhost machine.